# Cookies that won't delete

Tags: c#, cookies

I feel like I have been eaten by the cookie monster. I delete cookies and they come right back.
On logout, I execute this code:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DeleteCookie("UserId");
        DeleteCookie("UserName");

        Session.Abandon();
        GoToPublicHomePage();
    }

    private void DeleteCookie(string name)
    {
        if (Request.Cookies[name] != null)
        {
            HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(name);
            cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
            Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
        }
    }
```

Just before the "GoToPublicHome()" call, I check the Request.Cookies and the UserId and UserName cookies are in Response.

In my Global.asax --> Session_Start code which executes immediately after the GoToPublicHome call, they have come back... like a bad penny.

Comment: It seems you have 2 questions here: why does it create a new Cookie? and Why is the expiration date not set? Is it correct. Can you provide a more detailed question?

Answer (score 1):

The code you write instructs .Net to create a new HttpCookie, not to create "only if not exists".
On the MSDN page there is an example:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcookie.aspx

Comment: I have substantially revised the code, but still encounter the problem. Appreciate any help you can give.

Comment: When the user activate the action that "GoToPublicHomePage", is it in the same context than the page that had set the Cookie? I.e.: you click login at www.example.com/login.html, and you click logout at www.example.com/private/index.html. You need to check the "Path" property of the Cookie you delete is the same path as the Cookie you set

Answer (score 0):

How about `Response.Cookies.Remove(name)`?

Comment: Tried that and every variation I can think of. And Response doesn't contain any cookies until I put them there. I have tried Request.Cookies.Remove, but everything I read points to setting the expiration date as the way to delete them. The cookies that are re-appearing have no expiration date, so they look like sesion cookies instead of domain cookies.